# React side component will not work with position sticky

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component on the left column where it is used as a filter box. I have tried applying the position sticky css but it does nothing. If I do position fixed , the right where products are displayed comes over and ruins the whole layout. I would like this box to move down with the page. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. There is no overflow property in the parents either. I have also included the top 0 as well.

This is the how the component looks like

[image: filter component]

Comment: Please share the code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)

Comment: Instead of `sticky` use `position: fixed`, and give is some position on the screen by using `top: ##px; left:0px` for example. 
This does not fancy scroll with the page or something, and probably will have the same result as your `position: absolute`. To fix that, you need to position the other content too. Or add some empty div as a replacement for this block

Comment: @DeepuReghunath might get in trouble if I share code, but its just a component with basic css. No Overflow property, i know this isnt helpful but cant risk getting in trouble

Comment: @Leroy no way to use position sticky? I tried that and it kind of threw off a bunch of layouts so I wanted to avoid it

Comment: @Leroy it also ruins mobile view

Comment: just share the code  that you try so far

Comment: all i have tried so far is literally position: sticky; and top: 0; @DeepuReghunath

Comment: Making elements sticky or absolute, removes their DOM "relationship" to other elements. Usually you can make it stick or absolute, relative to some parent DOM element, but that's just for boundries of the sticky element. I think you have to share the output of the HTML and CSS, because just making stuff sticky isn't going to work. When you need it to be sticky, all the other elements will move, and another solution for those elements needs to be applied